# Excel: Formatting assistance for rows with no values

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, formatting

I've constructed a spread sheet of people vs garment options for a year 12 jumper, the peoples names are organised in rows and the option in columns. I would really like the whole row a persons name occupies to be highlighted when there are no values in their row. So far i have managed to make their row change colour when their are no values in the first cell otherwise I've had no avail.

Help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done. Take a look [at this](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/microsoft-office/how-to-use-excel-2010s-new-conditional-formatting-with-references/) for the main information.

Select Conditional Formatting > New Rule. Select "Use a formula...".

For the formula, I'm assuming that we're starting with A2 (with name data) and B2 being blank will cause the row to have a color.

```
=ISBLANK($B2)
```

Multiple cells should work as

```
=OR(ISBLANK($B2),ISBLANK($C2),ISBLANK($D2))
```

Set your format (background color) as you wish.

Also, maybe this will work (if the name isn't there, the row won't turn red anymore):

```
=AND(NOT(ISBLANK($A2)),OR(ISBLANK($B2),ISBLANK($C2)))
```

You may want to replace the `OR` with `AND` - It depends on exactly what your sheet looks like. Also take a look at `COUNTBLANK` and `COUNTA` - They may help if you need every column in a row filled out. See [the first response on this page](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/426877-isblank-function-multiple-cells.html#post2109455)